# downloading android source problems

Tags: android, android-source, repository

I'm very new to this. please forgive any misuse of terminology.

I am following the steps on source.android.com to download the source for android 4.2.2_r1

I did the steps where I initialized the repo and repo init like so:
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.2.2_r1

I've also done
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master

followed my repo sync to pull down the android source tree

My question, or problem, is I want my target to be manta. The lunch command displays the following options:
     1. full-eng
     2. full_x86-eng
     3. vbox_x86-eng
     4. full_maguro-userdebug
     5. full_tuna-userdebug
     6. full_panda-eng

no mantas.

I hope that made sense and someone can guide me.

Comment: You seem to be struggling with English here. At least I can't understand much of what you're saying. What is really the problem?

Comment: exactly what it says...I did the `repo sync` after `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.2.2_r1' when I enter `lunch` manta is not a listed option, which is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy method to add builds to lunch.

First, check if there is a manta folder inside `android_source/device/`

if it does exist, all you have to do is copy the `vendorsetup.sh` from one of the options that does show up in lunch and paste it into the manta folder and tweak its contents slightly.

Now, all you need to do is rerun the . build/envsetup.sh
and you should see manta in lunch

Comment: Launch instead of lunch maybe? :D

Comment: The Android tool to build for a device is actually called lunch! lol

Comment: ah well, now I learned something new :D

Comment: I couldn't even find a android_source/device folder? (sorry if it sounds stupid I'm naive when it comes to this)

Comment: try these

first do a `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.2.2_r1`  
and then do a `repo sync`..
don't do a `repo init` with `-b master`
The android master branch is always empty..you are expected to use one of the several versions of android source rather than master

Comment: The fact that you got lunch to work with those outputs suggests that there is a device folder..

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i've actually done the `repo init` for android 4.2.2_r1 but got the same output with lunch hence why i posted this question.

Comment: I did it again (`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.2.2_r1` and then `repo sync`) and when I enter `lunch` it says 
"No such file"